# Allow users to cancel their own moderator attention flags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags

During my very first days on Stack Oveflow, I flagged some questions for being off-topic. I now consider those flags to be invalid, and I clearly understand the reasons why I shouldn't have flagged those posts.

Those flags are currently still in the "active" state, which means either they're still in the review queue, or haven't been declined or approved by the moderators yet for some reason.

So, my question is: **why can't users cancel their pending moderator flags?** I think that chance might help to decrease the queues which is a benefit for moderators team, and might be granted with an access pattern similar to raise flags - general privilege at some reputation level, amount based on total reputation, explicit reason to revoke flag, like *I now understand that [put_subject_here] is not an offtopic on SO as [subject] is a tool used for software development primarily*.

Comment: Having it take long for your flag to get tended to is a direct result of [the size of the close vote queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252586/regarding-the-stack-overflow-close-review-queue). [There's a request here somewhere](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222410/flags-convert-to-close-votes-but-is-it-retroactive) that asks that, once reaching 3k reputation, you'll be able to convert these to close votes.

Comment: @Dukeling Does that means that 3k-rep close votes queue is the one "place" where flag either deemed helpful or declined/disputed?

Comment: @AlexeyMalev: yes, that's indeed the case for close/duplicate flags (unless someone else happens to find the question and there are enough votes to close the question). If no one else has also cast a close vote or flag on the question, that is currently hidden.

Comment: All the "it should be closed for another reason..." or "it's a duplicate" flags get sent there (the rest goes to the elected moderators). A few users then decide whether it belongs here or not (5 users are needed to close it, and votes / flags can age away if users decide it doesn't belong here), after which your flag is presumably marked as either helpful or declined/disputed.