# 9200 Close Votes in the queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

Why can't SO have a trial giving reviewers like myself a probation for reviewing and closing items on the queue - say 10 per day?

That would give us a chance to help out and show that the 3000 reputation limit isn't always appropriate.

Comment: Are you suggesting we give everyone access, risking millions of bad reviews?

Comment: @Oded: wait, would "millions" be more or less than the number of bad reviews we get from people who *have* earned the privilege? It's hard to tell. :P

Comment: No comment, @Wooble, no comment.

Comment: Millions *more*. ;)

Comment: That's like suggesting that teenagers be given a different speed limit than adults.

Comment: I'm really sure that the number of reviewers is not the problem.

Comment: no, not everyone, just give me a chance, or, alternatively, give me 769 points and I'll get started the same day:)

Comment: a lot of downvotes, obviously this idea is not appreciated and may people feel very strongly that this is not the solutio, or even part of the solution ...

Comment: @Philip You're proposing a quantity over quality system when it comes to reviews.  Past experience has shown, from other queues such as the suggested edit queue, that this is a *very* bad idea.  Maintaining a high standard of quality when reviewing is very important, even if it means lower throughput.

Comment: more interesting question would be, why [SO doesn't make CV queue comfortable for users _already eligible_ for working in it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252600/839601): "Sharp drop at 10-50 likely indicates that many users find it difficult to work in review queue. Drop after 250 (silver bagde) suggests that even after substantial amount of reviews, many users still fail to discover a way to work productively..." 9200 questions is only a week of work for 200 reviewers (note SO has ~20,000 eligible users)

Comment: I guess I'm just jealous and want the power too much

Comment: @gnat - your reasoning that the queue could be cleared in a week assumes no additional questions flow into the queue. I think the concern is the queue is not at a steady state, and the number of questions in the queue is growing without bound.

Comment: @theMayer assuming additional questions, queue would be cleared in two weeks instead of one. As for your concern, I tend to share it but, you see, with so much "closing potential" in their hands I can also understand reluctance of SE team to try a _more productive_ approach. Think of it, in theory 20,000 eligible users can simply close every new question, good and bad ones - they've got enough close votes for that

Comment: guys, I just want the power, I can see from the number of downvotes it's not the solution :)

Comment: why cant we allow close vote reviewers of other sites to review it too,

Answer (score 4):

Of course a predetermined limit won't be appropriate for everyone. However, limits like this exist in life in order to ensure that the greatest amount of people can "work" in order to achieve the most possible with the smallest amount of errors. That is to say that errors are expected and a limit is set at a level to ensure that the error rate is acceptable for the task at hand.

SE chose the 3k limit a while ago. All reviewers are not perfect but in order to change it you'd need some sort of data that would prove that the change in the level of the limit would not increase the proportion of bad reviews beyond that acceptable level.

It would be reasonable to assume that a way of doing this would be to get the questions flagged to close by all users with your reputation that were subsequently closed. Then you'd need to determine whether the proportion of questions re-opened and compare it to the proportion by users with more than 3k.

Comment: Is this data available on the statistics pages?

Comment: It's not, but it may be in [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com) @theMayer.

Comment: That is where I was referring. I was wondering if you knew if such statistics were available (some data might be somewhat sensitive, I don't know). thx.