# Review Queue per Tag on main tag page?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I just noticed this while looking at [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

[image]

There's 1,022 reviewable (i.e. close vote reviewable) items for the Java tag.  When did this feature get added?  Is it updated in (relative) real time?

Answer (score 2):

It was one of the proposals in how to get more users [do some work in the close vote queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252586/regarding-the-stack-overflow-close-review-queue).

From the answer to the original [feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202261/easy-close-review-queue-filtering-interface)

> [This feature was implemented and went out in build rev 2014.5.16.2252 on meta and 2014.5.16.1610 on sites.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231856/158100)

this was made public on May, 19th 2014 but given the buildnumbers probably went live on May, 16th 2014.