# When 10K Close Votes will be reviewed?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

I have just started giving review for Close Vote. There are almost 10K reviews are pending and everyday it is getting increased. Before few days it was 9.6K and yesterday it has reached at 9.9K. Now, its almost 10K and I know there are lot of users who have more than 3K reps. but, they are not taking their responsibilities. So, I am just asking about it that what we can do to maintain Close Vote reviews. Should we need to apply any strict rule that ever user has to follow. for example give at-least 20 Close Vote reviews in a week otherwise user cannot post the Answer. Or user can earn some reps by completing 50 reviews in a day.

I am just asking about your opinion. Can we provide that kind feature to encourage the user for Close Vote reviews?

Possible this question has been asked before. But, still its not resolved. So, I am asking about to give any feature or create a rule that encourage the users to give reviews for Close Vote.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252586/regarding-the-stack-overflow-close-review-queue

Comment: 10K is nothing.  It used to be up over 100K before changes mentioned in @rene's comment.

Comment: hehehe another question has been added in Close Vote review queue by me. :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> give at-least 20 Close Vote reviews in a week otherwise
>   user cannot post the Answer

I think that is the most terrible idea I've seen. The main goal of this site is to provide answers to questions, not to empty the close-vote queue. Forcing people to do it is more likely to drive them away or (even worse) make them sloppy-click their way through their quota.

Personally, after doing close to 700 close-reviews I'm at the point where I just get sick of looking at all the garbage questions that gets posted, and I've come to the conclusion that no matter how many questions we close they just keep coming. I think spending so much time on close reviews was a contributing factor to loosing interest in answering questions. **Forcing** me to do it would just make me stop completely.

> Or user can earn some reps by completing 50 reviews in a day

This is a better idea, but it can also lead to sloppy reviews. I'm also not convinced that people who review only for the rep are the best suited reviewers.

Also, purging the close vote queue would just cure the symptom, not the underlying problem which is the amazing amount of bad questions that get posted. I would much rather see a solution to that problem.

Comment: I am agree with you @ivarni and you are absolutely right that gives too many sloppy reviews. So, what should we do to resolve this problem?

Comment: I'm not convinced that it *is* a problem, I think it's a symptom of another problem, which is all those bad questions being posted in the first place.