# How flag questions like "please do my job for me"?

Tags: discussion, triage

This question is about Triage queue and VLC queue. I do not mean to put a VLQ flag. That in Triage is no longer available and was never in VLQ.

What is the proper way to flag for these kind of questions? I see many questions like this.

For instance [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6402661).

I have followed the [diagram](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278499/2573335) in this way, but I'm unsure what flag is appropriate.

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Flag to close as "Needs more focus" (successor of "Too broad") or "Needs details or clarity" (successor of "Unclear what you are asking"). These sorts of questions get closed every day for those reasons.

Consider leaving a comment of course as well. Sometimes people just don't get how this site works.

Comment: ok. I got it, but maybe the comments should be available on flags window. Like in VLQ queue "Recommend Close"

Comment: @OneWay It sounds like they will be enabling the comments box (if they haven't already) but given that there are no pro-forma comments for the Close Votes queue, I doubt we'll see them here