# How to flag/close as "not a code-writing service"

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I sometimes come across questions in which the author gives you requirements to **write a program**, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43703898/accepting-a-string-or-char-input-in-an-int-variable-program-in-java) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43703950/java-merge-numbers-in-a-two-dimensional-array-like-a-game). These are not questions for StackOverflow, so I was trying to flag them, but did not find an appropriate flag for this. I even came across one question where the OP said they would pay whoever did the program through PayPal. I think this is completely unacceptable(I could not find that question to post, sorry).

How would I flag these questions? *Low quality post? Unclear what you're asking? In need of moderator attention?* After all, this is a **Question and Answer** site, not a **Requirements and Program-writing** site. Thanks in advance to those who comment and answer.

Comment: First one as *unclear what you're asking* or *too broad* and the second one as *unclear* as well. This usually also applies to most questions that are purely asking for someone to write code.

Comment: well, in the first example, it is very clear what the poster is asking, he wants to know _How to write a java program that accepts a string or char input and stores it in an int variable_

Comment: Shouldn't there be a "not a code writing service" flag too, as this does apply to many questions?

Comment: I've put both on hold as "unclear" - although the first one might be salvageable given the OP tried to put some code in a comment (although it's unclear what the problem they have doing so is - do they get errors, do they not now how to use xyz correctly, etc...) - the second one is just a requirement, a wall of text and no discernible question . As an aside - there's not much point leaving comments saying *we are not a code-writing service* - If you want to leave a comment you can do so more productively by pointing them to [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I edited the second one, so it is readable and has a question, but the question is still "How do I write this code?", which is not for this site.

Comment: @theProgrammer101 Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334892/no-code-included-flag and its duplicate.

Comment: @JonClements My edit for the second question just got approved, so it is readable. Here is when the "not a code writing service" flag comes in handy...

Comment: The *unclear* close reason implicitly fits those cases as well. It's sort of a *"Surely you don't just want us to write code for you, so what is your specific question about the problem statement you're given."*. The *too broad* reason fits because there are usually way too many possible ways to implement a requirement and since such questions usually show a general lack of understanding of general concepts possible answers would end up being too long.

Comment: I understand @Keiwan's comment and I kind of agree with it. I have read similar statements elsewhere. My problem is that it reads like a laywers argument, not an answer that a normal person would understand. As the OP says, many of these question are perfectly clear about what the asker wants, they want some code written. So closing as "unclear" appears to be very much the wrong close reason. With that argument the word "unclear" is being given a meaning that is not in the dictionary.

Comment: @AdrianHHH: at which point you downvote and move on. Asking for code being written is not actually off-topic. We write code in answers *all the time* already. It becomes an issue is that is all we are doing, because then it is too broad for our platform. Hence the Too Broad close reason applying. This is how we are *already* handling such posts, and it works just fine. I don't see a need for a separate specific reason, because that's then easily open for abuse (suddenly everything is asking for  code).

Comment: see also: [How flag questions like “please do my job for me”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278612/how-flag-questions-like-please-do-my-job-for-me)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic #3