# Where are the docs/post on how triage is supposed to work (including actionable items like criteria to apply)?

Tags: support, questions, triage

I have a question on how to apply triage, but I'm having problems finding a post detailing what is supposed to be done.

There is a related post that discusses the feature request and it looks like it provides an initial implementation for testing: [Let's have an explicit triage system for questions from new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236537/173448). But the post's screen shots do not include the selections of *Look OK*, *Should be improved* and *Unsalavgeable*, so I'm pretty sure its a bit dated and things have have changed since the post.

Additionally, the *Linked* questions and *Related* questions don't appear to offer a link to the final doc or post for the triage system.

Where are the doc or post detailing how triage is supposed to work, and what criteria I should apply to classify a question?

Comment: this one? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage

Comment: Thanks rene. That looks like testing too. It lacks criteria to apply for the classifications of *Look OK*, *Should be improved* and *Unsalavgeable*. I'm fairly certain I have my head around *Look OK*. But the other two are not clear to me. I updated the question to include the question on criteria because that's the crux of my problem.

Comment: I click Should be improved if it needs an edit. Unsalvageable is basically when I would normally close vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant docs are in the review queue itself:

[image: click (more)]

If any of that isn't clear, please post a question here and I'll see what I can do to make those instructions more useful.

I elaborated a bit on my personal theory in my answer to [Triage gray areas - what should we do when the question is borderline?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278461/triage-gray-areas-what-should-we-do-when-the-question-is-borderline):

> ...we look for things that might make questions more appealing to answerers and easier to find for others with the same problems. Is it...
>
> - ...About programming?
> - ...Reasonably-scoped?
> - ...Clearly written?
> - ...Detailed enough to identify the problem, with a descriptive title?
> - ...Nicely formatted?
> - ...With relevant tags?
>
> If so, I'd say it Looks OK. If it's lacking *all* of these, it's probably Unsalvageable. Everything else Needs *some* Improvement - but if the need isn't great, it could still be OK, while if it is severe the chances of it being salvaged are still pretty slim.

Comment: Thanks Shog. Let me get another question opened for the particulars of the Triage question that triggered this question. [Application of Triage on "Graphical Layout issue..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281100/608639).