# Asking a user to improve their question when they don't have the necessary points?

Tags: discussion, new-users, triage, images

This is related to [Where are the docs/post on how triage is supposed to work (including actionable items like criteria to apply)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281097/608639) and [How to handle “Graphical Layout issue…” in Triage review queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281100/608639).

The scenario I have a question about is when a new user wants to include an image in his/her question, but lacks the necessary points to do so. In addition, the question is in the Triage queue (as opposed to another queue where there's more latitude). An example is shown below with a link to an image:

[image]

Kicking it back to the user with a *Should be improved* for immediate improvement is a dead end because the user does not have the necessary points to add the image.

Do we select *Looks OK* when only the image is missing so it gets routed to another queue (and hope an editor adds the image)?

Or do we select *Should be improved* and wait for the user to gain the necessary points (or an editor to add the image)?

Or do we select *Not salvageable* because the user lacks the necessary points to add the image?

How would the site like this handled?

---

**EDIT**: I had the support tag because I wanted an official answer from the site on how to handle the scenario. Its really as simple as one of three answers. Once I know how to handle the scenario for this question, I can apply it to future questions.

I did not add the discuss tag because I'm not interested in an endless debate that Meta is famous for. If you want to discuss and argue it, then you should probably open another question. I just want to be told what to do for this scenario.

Comment: @Jon - I want an answer from the site on how to handle this feature of the site. I'm not interested in an endless debate on the subject. Please remove the discuss tag, and add the support tag.

Comment: You're more than welcome to revert the change - ultimately there's a very thin line between support and discussion given the subject...

Comment: There is no *definitive answer* to this question, and therefore it's not "support". You're asking for a general discussion of how this type of question should be handled, and IMO the discussion tag is relevant and the support tag is not. <strike>If you want guidance *only on the question you've cited*, add a `specific-question` tag, and then it's not a discussion.</strike> (Oh, wait - I see it's there in the [duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281100) you posted.)

Comment: @Ken - I cited that question, but its not a duplicate. If processes surrounding the Triage queue was properly documented, then it could be a duplicate of the first question I asked. But its not. This question is quite specific: how to handle a question in the Triage queue when the question needs to be improved, but the author does not have the necessary points to improve it.

Comment: I see two questions asking about how to handle the same specific question in Triage. I'm not sure how they're different, although this one is much more clear regarding what you're asking in general. The other one says "Should we take this action (edit/vote this way/vote that way/leave alone)", and this one says "Should we vote this way/that way". I don't see much difference, although I gave you the benefit of the doubt and didn't VTC as a duplicate.

Comment: @jww I understand you are really interested in the new tools, but do you really need to ask 3 questions that reference the same terrible SO question.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - its a poor question, but its a good learning tool to figure out how Triage is supposed to work. Sorry about the extra noise, though.

Comment: @Ken - [the first question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281100/608639) asked if editors are supposed to take actions with a question in the Triage queue. This question asks if we should mark a triage questions as *Should be improved* when the poster does not have the necessary points to improve the question. They are distinct issue to me, so they were asked as separate questions.

Comment: I'll avoid restating what @psubsee2003 said, but I agree that posting several times here related to a single Triage question maybe means that you're overthinking. Deal with the question and move on; there's no definitive *one size fits all* answer as you seem to be looking for here. Triage, like reviews and voting, often is subjective, and frequently calls for exercising your own judgement. If you can't decide how to deal with a specific question, skip it and deal with the next one instead. If it concerns you that much, open the post in a new tab, fix the link, and then mark it as "OK".

Comment: If you have so many doubts, I recommend you can use chat instead of MSO. You can use rooms like the Tavern on the Meta, and perhaps chat with Shog and others about this.

Comment: @Infinite Recursion - I don't use chat or chat rooms, so that's not a viable option for me. Plus, its probably better to document it for future reference so others can benefit from the answer provided by the site. So a Question/Answer is probably the best venue.

Comment: @Ken - *"but I agree that posting several times here related to a single Triage question maybe means that you're overthinking"* - if I would have mashed three or four different questions into one, then someone would have complained about that, too (and rightfully so).

Answer (score 14):

There's a rep threshold for images for a reason. Very few new questions from new users make appropriate use of images. They drop in images of code, or they drop in images *instead* of code. Worrying about the rare possibility that a question might be great <del>except for an image</del> seems a bad use of worry. New users should just 'use their words' to describe their problem. This awful excuse for a question didn't need an image; it needed a coherent description of what the OP wanted, what the OP tried, and what the oP got.

Answer (score 8):

First, the the question of fixing images on an otherwise good post.  "Should Be Improved" has the guidance text of:

> **Should Be Improved** for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable

I strongly point to the "or others" part.  If you can fix it, do so. If the OP lacked the rep to add an image and it would help, you are part of the "or others".  It should be improved. Mark the review as such, and then go fix the question (and fix the spelling, punctation, capitalization, title, and everything else too).

For that post, there are other problems with it that adding the image wouldn't be sufficient to make it a clear and answerable question.

(There is an interesting question to be considered here of should questions that should be improved by the OP (not others) but failing that question should be closed - how should they be triaged?  My take, they are unsalvageable, but that doesn't fit the guidance text exactly either.)

If you look at the review itself: https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/6573525 and the post https://stackoverflow.com/q/27641780/289086 you will see that it has been closed as unclear.  What headline? What is the layout? What should it look like?  There is quite a bit more information that is necessary.

Unless the OP of that question takes sufficient measures ***that only they can*** it should be closed.

Comment: Thanks Michael. As for, *"If you can fix it, do so"* - are we supposed to do that (do we have authority to do that)? Is that how this queue was designed? Is that how its intended to be used? That's what this question is about: [How to handle “Graphical Layout issue” in Triage review queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281100/608639). If we start fixing questions in triage, then it is just an alternate Low Quality Post queue. In this case, it confuses processes and its wasted effort. Since that's probably not the case, there's something that differentiates Triage from Low Quality Posts.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to give the proper feedback for fixing the question as soon as possible?  As the question is fresher in the OP's mind there is a better opportunity for them to help answer any clarifying comments. That the source for the link comes from an 'organic' front page hit or from 'should be improved' doesn't matter.  What matters is that good questions get visibility.  If you can make it into a good question, do it.

Comment: I agree about good feedback early. But if I do that, I might not be using the site's Triage feature as intended. If I am not using it as intended or designed, then that means I'm making up the policies and rules as I go (and as ***I*** see fit). To me, that's a bigger party foul. Everyone has to use the site consistently so the user gets a high quality, consistent experience.

Comment: @jww you will note that after a question gets three "looks good" reviews there's that wiggle of the up vote button (the third looks good reviewer sees this as will anyone going back to the review).  You are *supposed* to interact with the question after you do your review - be it up vote, edit, or close vote. Not everyone has the time nor skill to make a good edit (so that isn't emphasized), but it doesn't mean it shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 1):

> Not salvageable

Certainly not. It is salvageable even if it isn't by the OP. Also, just because it doesn't have the image embedded doesn't make it a bad question. It just means that an edit is in order

Either "Looks ok" or "Should be improved" I would say would be acceptable. However, my understanding is that "Should be improved" is for questions which badly need help. The example question simply needs a quick edit by a user who is capable of doing so. No reason to make more work for others or the system.

"Looks ok" should be used and if you can and are willing to fix the problem then do so.

Comment: You're kidding, right? How could this ever be a useful question? It's missing about 10 tons of detail about what the OP tried, expected, and got.

Comment: @bmargulies - I provided an example of a user adding a link to an image because he/she did not have the points to add the image. The entire question had more troubles, but I only used it because it was exemplary for this particular issue.

Comment: @bmargulies I'm afraid I'm not kidding at all. The question here is not about if this particular question is good. The question is if the reviewer feels that the only thing needed is adding something they don't have the reputation for.