# Suggestion for rewording of triage review guidance

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, triage

There are three categories.

#### Looks OK:

> **Looks OK** for questions that can be found, understood and answered as-is

And that looks OK.  One *might* want to consider adding in a bit about formatting, but its otherwise good.  If one was to tweak it, the following wording might be in order:

> **Looks OK** for questions that are formatted well, findable, understandable, and can be answered as-is

---

The problem arises with the distinction between should be improved and unsalvageable.  There are other suggestions with breaking should be improved into 'should be improved by the community' and 'should be improved by the person asking the question' as there are things that the latter can do that the former cannot.

Setting that aside, lets look at a [flow chart](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278499/289086) and try to put those paths into words:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rcat.png]

Should be improved currently reads:

> **Should Be Improved** for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable

Let's assume for a this that the author *doesn't* know the proper way to ask a question. While this *should* be improved by the author, lets work form the position that the author can't (language barrier), won't (addicted to 'i' and 'thanks in advance'), or doesn't understand what should be improved (a new user who wants to ask a good question).

From this we should change it to:

#### Should be improved:

> **Should Be Improved** for questions where the *community* can improve the quality resulting in a question that is clear and answerable

Note the emphasis on the community.  With the Help and Improvement queue this isn't just pushed off into nowhere and left for the author to improve.

That brings us to Unsalvageable.  This currently reads:

> **Unsalvageable** for questions that cannot or should not be answered and must therefore be removed from the site

This reads a bit hard. Furthermore, lots of people reviewing in triage appear to have the perception that this is only for the worst of the worst.  Things that moderators [wouldn't argue with a VLQ flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93606/165773) on it.

The problem with this interpretation is that questions that should be closed where there is a path for the author to refine the post and have it be a possibly good question (unclear, needs a mcve, too broad) get put into "should be improved" and sent to the H&IQ which leads us to the dissatisfaction with that queue.

People aren't sending the 'on topic - no' to unsalvageable. They aren't sending the 'specific problem - no' to unsalvageable.

Lets look at focusing this review option on things that the *author* can do.

#### Unsalvageable:

> **Unsalvageable** for questions where improvement must be done by the author before the community can answer it, or for questions that do not fit in the [Stack Overflow Q&A topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

---

As an aside, it would be interesting to see if there is a relationship between the quality of triage reviews compared to the reputation of the reviewer and their activity in the H&IQ.

The measure of quality would be "reviewed post is positively scored and open after a week".  "Looks OK" and "Should be improved" would be 'hits' for this criteria.  Questions that are either negatively scored, closed, or deleted after a week would be hits for "unsalvageable".

Why do I ask this? Because any change in the criteria needs to be communicated to those who are in good faith being too lenient on posts between the should be improved and unsalvageable review options.

Why? Just looking at others who have co-reviewed with me:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7619389 - 1.3k user said looks good; 700 user said should be improved (closed by a mod as too broad)
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7618094 - 1.3k user said looks good; 1.8k user said should be improved (closed as 'debugging help needs mcve')
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7606941 ([rev 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29504396/1)) 600 rep said looks ok; 600 rep said looks ok
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7594629 ([rev 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29482614/1)) 600 rep said should be improved, 1.9k rep said should be improved, 19k rep said should be improved
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/7481931 (closed as recommendation) 1.7k said should be improved, 2.6k said should be improved.

Communicating the close reasons and quality expectations to these users (you will note that most are sub 3k rep) is key to properly feeding the help and improvement queue.  When questions that are all multi line inline code get "looks ok", we haven't done a good enough job at setting the expectations for what a question should look like to those users.

Until that is done, in conjunction with improving the wording on the triage review options, the help and improvement queue will continue to be fed with questions where it's mostly "close this" rather than "fix this" (and more than a few 'this should get its markdown fixed before it gets too many down votes' will go through as 'Looks OK').

Comment: Yes. I want this.

Comment: Could we add that flowchart or a more detailed flowchart in the Triage section itself? I feel like that would drastically improve Triage reviews. We'd just have to add a small disclaimer like:  "This is for guideline purposes only, make your own detailed judgement"

Comment: Further reading: [Difference between Should Be Improved and Unsalvageable in Triage](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287026/1768232)

Comment: [I agree](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287473/1026459)

Comment: I suggest that changing the triage review *guidance* in itself is not enough; the *button captions* must be updated as well. As [Kevin](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1340389/kevin) suggests in his comments under [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291645/512728), *reword "Should be Improved" to "The community can fix this" and "Unsalvageable" to "Only OP can fix this," or something along those lines.*

Comment: I suggest encouraging people to **Skip** more often; I suspect many misjudgements occur on questions on topics with which the reviewer is unfamiliar. In particular whether the question supplies sufficient context is then often unclear.

Answer (score 37):

This isn't a bad idea, but... I'm skeptical that it'll accomplish much.

The guidance on the review page itself spends most of its time hidden. The goal is to give new reviewers a broad overview of what they're supposed to be doing there, but once that's done it gets out of the way.

Indeed, it might be worth putting some effort into *displaying it* more often - for instance, after you've failed an audit.

But for Triage specifically, there's an even bigger elephant in the room...

### I'm flagging this question for... *reasons...*

[image: the flagging dialog]

Yeah. *That* mess.

Go through the examples you listed and, pretending you're *not* a long-term veteran with a deep understanding of All The Rules, try to figure out what option on that flag dialog corresponds to the problems present in those questions...

Spoiler: it's the one about "this site's standards". My hypothesis is that a lot of folks who *would* be choosing "Unsalvageable" see that dialog and... Just give up. Clearly, the posts need some improvement; whether or not they meet some unspecified "standards" and should be closed is less apparent.

So I looked back through the past couple of days worth of logs. Turns out, folks give up before clicking "it should be closed..." somewhere > 20% of the time *when working through Triage*. Another 20% give up after getting to the close dialog.

One of the humbling lessons I learned from Close Review was that a *lot* of reviewers don't have the close reasons memorized; they'd compulsively open the dialog just to refresh their memories before making a decision. So I'm less worried about the folks who decide to choose a different option after getting to the close dialog, but the folks whose first impulse **is** "unsalvageable" and then give up on the first page concern me: we're driving them to make bad decisions by not giving them the information they need.

What does this mean in practical terms? I took a look at 1712 or so recent reviews that were concluded as "Should Be Improved", where fewer than 2 reviewers chose "Unsalvageable". 107 of them had *at least* two requests for the flag dialog. I think that's a reasonably conservative estimate of how many incorrect decisions we could've potentially avoided by improving this dialog...

Of course, the actual damage could be much greater. Remember, close flags are [intended as training wheels](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/), positioned not just as an input mechanism but as a form of *training* for new user-moderators. This is the same dialog that *everyone* under 3K sees - if a sizable portion of flaggers aren't clicking through to the close options (and they aren't...) then that's a whole lot of people who aren't being educated on what options are available.

### Being forthright: flagging options that say what they mean

So... We need a better flagging dialog for questions. Here are my goals:

- clearly distinct options
- descriptions that cover the breadth of each option in sufficient detail to allow new flaggers to make a sane decision *before* selecting it.
- same *number* of options as today... or fewer.

Here's my first stab at reworking this:

> I am flagging to report that this question is...
>
> - **spam**
>   Exists only to promote a product or service, [does not disclose the author's affiliation](/help/promotion).
> - **inappropriate**
>   A reasonable person would find this content [inappropriate for respectful discourse.](/help/be-nice)
> - **should be closed...**
>   This question is completely unclear, incomplete, overly-broad, primarily opinion-based or is not about [programming] as described in [the help center](/help/on-topic), and it is unlikely to be fixed via editing.
> - **a duplicate...**
>   This question has been asked before and already has an answer.
> - **in need of moderator intervention**
>   A problem not listed above that requires action by a moderator. *Be specific and detailed!*

Thoughts?

Comment: Perhaps reviewers should be able to vote 'Unsalvageable' without flagging. (But could we change the wording of the hints anyway? Is it not trivial to do?)

Comment: Would this be brought to answers?

Comment: That's substantially better, although the last one is still misleading: flagging ♦ is sometimes necessary for problems that are not so much "serious" as *unusual*, like making a question (un-)CW or deleting all the comments on a post because they're obsolete.

Comment: New users frequently use the last option for things like "I need an answer urgently!", @Nathan. Appreciate any suggestions for clarifying the sorts of problems one might actually benefit from bugging moderators about.

Comment: Maybe something like *"in need of moderator **intervention** -> A serious problem that requires an action **only available** to a moderator"*?

Comment: Agreed, Shog, and @Radiodef's suggestion seems to be getting a lot closer. Maybe swap out "serious" for "significant" and see if that does the trick?

Comment: Also, possibly noting that the option is intended for a problem that doesn't fit in to the other categories e.g. *"**some other** significant problem ..."*.

Comment: Does inappropriate go to sub-reasons? Or is it more like a VLQ flag?

Comment: @bjb568 It seems to go to the typical close reason sub-menu. *"unclear, incomplete, overly-broad, primarily opinion-based..."*

Comment: That's a good suggestion, @Radiodef - edited!

Comment: Given you're the second person to ask that, it appears I was remiss in removing the word "close" from the dialog entirely. Re-added.

Comment: This should probably be its own meta question. I don't like the idea that from now on "needs closing" means "unlikely to be fixed via editing". While *technically* correct, I thought the idea of putting a question on-hold or closing it should be a temporary state, until it's edited and improved.

Comment: "inappropriate" doesn't seem the right word for the third bullet; to me at least it brings to mind something more egregious than forgetting to post the code along with the error it throws. I suggest "cannot be properly answered" instead of "inappropriate".

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @pizza here; "inappropriate" seems too similar to "offensive." The "(should be closed)" sidebar certainly helps, but I think it might be a good idea to state that directly and have the option just be "should be closed..."

Comment: Personally, the reason I always found this dialog intimidating was because it's actually 2-3 layers deep, and some of the most useful/common reasons are buried in those deeper layers. I'd rather have a "flat" dialog showing me *all of the options* (with no space wasted on descriptions for the "top 5") so I actually knew what I was choosing from. Then show the full description on click/hover but before confirmation. Probably won't happen, but that's my $0.02.

Comment: @SecondRikudo *'I don't like the idea that from now on "needs closing" means "unlikely to be fixed via editing".'* Well, that is along the lines of what this question was originally about. As of right now the hints for 'Unsalvageable' read *"for questions that cannot or should not be answered and must therefore be removed from the site"* and *"this question has too many issues and is not worth fixing"*. That's essentially the description you don't like.

Comment: @SecondRikudo - I think we want to differentiate between things that can be improved by the community and things that only the poster can edit to clarify. Closing applies to the latter and "Should Be Improved" to the former.

Comment: Trying to keep the bold text short, @pizza; thinking of just going back to "should be closed" and using "inappropriate" instead of "offensive".

Comment: So, funny story @Second... I added that bit after Undo's comment, which (correctly) pointed out that this was approaching a more specialized wording for "Very Low Quality". Given that I'm trying to get these options to converge for questions *anyway*, it seems appropriate to strengthen that association. What are you concerned about, exactly? Folks not flagging questions that *are* likely to be fixed?

Comment: I wonder if 'should be closed' and 'duplicate' should be moved to the top of the list. This would more or less order the list by probability of use. 'Should be closed' in particular is probably the scary menu new users need to become familiar with. At least for Triage, I don't see a reason not to put it at the top or otherwise emphasize it. Users could be invited to click in to it because the other options are less likely to apply (and its generally obvious when they do).

Comment: I may as well post this here too: http://jsfiddle.net/ycepk0vu/

Comment: Ouch, now the 3rd bullet suffers from bjb-grammar: "question is should be closed". How about "is of [very] low quality and should be closed"? Folding VLQ flags here.

Comment: ...but gnat knows "All The Rules". It's impossible to pretend.

Comment: Well, I'd say it "needs improvement from the author" rather than it being "unlikely to be fixed via editing", or perhaps emphasize that YOU, the reviewer, can't fix by editing. We generally *want* people to edit and reopen their closed questions.

Comment: My only suggestion is to add "This has no serious issues that I can articulate, but it annoys the living &#@*&# out of me and I want to tell someone"

Comment: @TimPost and behind the scenes, clicking on that one should place a downvote (in the name of the user, not of Community) instead of a flag. This way, people may start learning the difference.

Comment: Keeping bold labels short is one thing, but "inappropriate" is so generic and vague that you might as well get rid of all the other options and just have that one. Sure, the description says "inappropriate for respectful discourse", but how many people even know what that means? Case in point: we're now getting more incorrect red flags than "please help me" flags per day - that's got to be a record.

Comment: @Tim Post: I'm curious to see how many would-be "please help me" flaggers that suggestion would catch.

Comment: We are getting a lot of bad flags due to the "inappropriate wording", I think we need to move that back to offensive or something in line with the Be Nice policy. Can we also move the "offensive" flag down the list? Being at the top people are applying it when it is flat out wrong.  Examples [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799571/how-to-create-shortcut-key-to-button), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799707/a-screenshot-with-printwindow-and-d3dxsavesurfacetofile), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797286/how-do-i-execute-the-sql-query-in-jquery) bad but not offensive.

Comment: "inappropriate wording" is but one of the reasons people are seeing fit to use the "inappropriate" flag today @bluefeet.

Comment: Shog, recently "Other" flag has been replaced with new wording, network wide - is this intended? [I asked about this at MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254097/165773)

Comment: The rewording and reorganisation is good and welcome, but the duplicate option is now accessible in both the new and existing path - duplicated, you could say :)

Comment: Suggestion for the first line: *I am flagging this question for the following reason.* The sentence ends there; the bullet list items are no longer forced to be its continuation.

Comment: “question is … should be closed” annoys me too, @2mkgz. I would choose [“question is … to be closed”](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/185839/57817).

Comment: I found the new *"Exists only to promote a product or service, does not disclose the author's affiliation."* confusing. Are *both* conditions to be met or *one* of them? For example, http://stackoverflow.com/a/29891573/1187415 (now deleted) seems to promote a product but shows the affiliation.  I am not a native english speaker, but perhaps an explicit "or" between the conditions would be helpful.

Comment: The duplicate option has been duplicated for close to two years now, @Luke. I guess it's indicative of something that you didn't notice until I rearranged them...

Comment: I don't think signing your name to your spam counts as *disclosure*, @Martin...

Comment: @Shog9 I was about to create a meta, but happened upon this post from [this duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321895/change-triage-guidelines-for-requires-editing). I **highly** recommend we change the wording of "Requires Editing" to remove "by the author", as mentioned in OP's original post. When I first started in the Triage queue, I made many mistakes, passing an edit to others where only the OP could add additions to the question to make it salvageable. (More specifically, exactly because of this wording).

Comment: Why does not search for duplicates each time ? And display the first similar questions at the top with a sentence like "It seems it's a duplicate, could you check ?".