# How is "Unclear what you're asking" a valid close reason for the Triage queue?

Tags: discussion

When you mark a question as unsalvageable in Triage you are presented with all the close reasons, including "Unclear what you're asking."

But how could that be a valid close reason in Triage if the main point of the Help and Improvement queue is to address this issue?

From the "Unclear what you're asking" help text:

> Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to
>   highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard
>   to tell exactly what you're asking.

Sounds to me like what H&I is for.

Comment: How would you "fix" this question: "How can I fdjosiejfokdsjfkosd in Java"?

Comment: If we can't tell what they are asking, how are we supposed to help them improve it?

Comment: @ryanyuyu That sounds more like spam than unclear.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg replace the spammy characters with just super-unclear text or _ambiguous_ text.  Like "How can I search in Java"?  Search for what?  Unclear seems like a great fit here, even better than too broad.

Comment: No, that's not what "spam" means.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I'de disagree and say that is a classical case of too broad.

Comment: Why do you think the "Help & Improvement" and "Triage" queues are mutually exclusive? Categorizing questions isn't an exact science, and there can be overlaps.

Comment: Yes, but I was under the impression that the majority of 'unclear' questions should fall under H&I. This seems not to be the case though...

Comment: I choose this flag if there is way to much to do, we should not write novels in the comments clearing everything up.

Comment: Many questions are unsalvageable without intervention by the question poster. You should only click "Should be improved" if you think there is enough information in the question to show what is being asked for, but it just needs some rewording or possibly formatting to make it clearer.

Comment: @TZHX Looking at my disputed flags, that needs to be communicated much more prominently.

Comment: @martin I agree. but it seems the people who matter don't. because it only affects people with < 3000 rep, suggestions to improve it will be met with "why bother".

Comment: @martin - We've been having a conversation about this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290915/19679 and the best ways to deal with problematic disputed flags from review. There's a disconnect at some point here, so something will need to be changed.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Podcast #63](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/03/podcast-63-the-plumbers-up-to-67-coins/) addresses this particular issue.  Listen in at about 10:37:

> So the triage queue is more or less working...it's certainly identifying three tiers of questions:  the best ones, the worst ones, and the ones in the middle.  The problem is it quickly became obvious as soon as we launched the help and improvement queue that the middle ones, which are supposed to be, these are salvageable by some kind soul who wants to put some time into editing them, are not always that.  We don't seem to be accurately labeling them.

From this, I get that the point of the Help and Improvement queue is to help questions which are salvageable *without* intervention from the OP.  Questions that are in triage that could be made better with help from the OP should be put on hold, so that the OP has time to edit the question with relevant details and information.

Think of it like the difference between:

> I'm working on a Java project which requires us to *foo* the *bar*.  I've tried *baz* but it didn't work.  Could I get a hand?

versus

> I'm working on a Java project which requires us to *foo* the *bar*.  I've tried to *baz*, but I got this strange `IllegalArgumentException` when I pass a negative value to this function.  I've mostly verified that we're passing the correct value to the function, but it still seems to be coming up with that exception.  What's going on?

Comment: Wow, I flag a lot on the queue and I get a lot of disputed flags but according to that, I need to flag soo much more, which I will now do.