# How should questions that look like homework be reviewed?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, disputed-review-audits

The [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636805/nodejs-split-large-file-into-chunks) seems to be for a homework, but there is no initial solution to be fixed. In addition the question is quite imperative with multiple constraints:

> I need to compress a folder into a multi-volume archive using nodejs,
> it could be zip, tar, etc. I can use any MIT licensed node package. I
> CANT use any external programs, rely on them being installed, or in
> PATH.
>
> Example: my_folder (size 30 MB), max volume size 10MB. I need to
> create:
>
> ```
> my_folder.zip.001
> my_folder.zip.002
> my_folder.zip.003
> ```
>
> Also the volumes should be readable by popular programs like: 7zip,
> winrar, etc.

Is that a post that "looks good" or needs "to be improved"?

---

#### Edit (after a few answers were given)

**Thanks for sharing your opinion**.
I didn't want to deliver the full audit story before receiving several non-biased opinions. I hope this temporary omission will not upset you.

None of you at this time is seeing this post as being really a good one. Neither did I. I suspected an audit because in spite of being a not so great request for support, it had already a high score of 16!

I answered *Yes, this post perfect!*, adding one point of reputation myself.

I see two problems:

- Reviewers are potentially penalized if they ask for the post to be improved.
- Such posts are guaranteed to see their score increasing if they are used for audits that are easy to identify.

The audit system should be fixed in my opinion.

[image: Result of the audit]

Comment: Maybe flag -> Too Broad

Comment: In my view, that would **definitely** need some editing to be in a fit shape for SO.

Comment: Definitely **not** "Looks Good"

Comment: I'd call this Too Broad or maybe even Unclear What You're Asking -- it's a list of requirements, but there's arguably no actual question included.

Comment: Man that was an audit?  That's a terrible audit choice.  Sometimes the automatic system fails.

Comment: The question also fits the "recommend book, tool, library, etc" off-topic category, so it's pretty much unsalvageable in the current form.

Answer (score 14):

**Nevermind** the fact that it is or isn't for an assignment.  Look at the *crux* of the question.  What do you see?

> I need to do X.  It needs to fit within Y constraints.  I can't use Z.
>
> Example:
>
> Also, it should be able to do W.

It's too broad.  ***Way*** too broad.

My advice would be only to say that a question "needs improvement" [if some kind soul off of the queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290977/1079354) can improve it without intervention from the OP.

Answer (score 4):

As you've noted, this definitely doesn't "Look Good". But likewise, there's no real *structural* problems with it (i.e. the grammar or formatting isn't what's wrong with it) - so sending it to "Should Be Improved" where it would be put up for editing doesn't seem likely to result another reviewer being able to edit it into shape. For a question like this, where its problems are less "quality" and more fundamentally the makeup of the question itself, the appropriate action would more likely be to flag it as Too Broad or Unclear What You're Asking, so that the asker is directly told to figure out how to re-ask their question in a form appropriate for Stack Overflow. It's going to likely require editing in some degree of what the asker has attempted so far before it would be a good question, which is something no other editor is likely to be able to provide.

Comment: I agree that there is nothing really bad in the question. It's well written and there is a real non trivial need behind. Furthermore the OP seems to me a very involved requester, as demonstrated by his own answer to his question 2 days later. But it's not a good audit item either.