# Triage Review - Questions that require editing from the author

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

What should I choose when a question definitely does not "Look OK", but does not require the attention of editors, specifically because only the author could provide the information needed to make the question good?

An example might be:

- When an author explains a problem with their code, but does not include the code.
- When a question explains an issue with a programming tool, but in order to be answer-able more details are needed.
- When a question explains an issue with a programming tool, but in order to be answer-able **many** more details are needed.
- A question that includes code and an error message, but not much else.

I listed those examples because I feel like many of the questions that fall under them could be "good" questions, but they require the time and attention of the author. If only the author had included a few (or many) key details, then the question would "Look OK". I feel that is so close to questions that "Require Editing" via the description on the triage page: "this question could be good, but requires some time and attention of editors".

So what's the correct response on my part?

- Do I say the question "**Looks OK**", even though it definitely doesn't? Even though it is low-quality and the author could have made the question high-quality by following our "How do I ask a good question?" guide
- Do I say that the question "**Requires Editing**", even though I know that would mean sending the question to editors when I know the only person for the job is the author?
- Do I say that the question is "**Unsalvageable**", even though I believe it doesn't have too many issues and is in fact fixable?

I have seen somewhat similar questions, which all have been answered by: "We need another option". If that is the case, when can we expect that "other option". Will it ever be provided? Is it being considered by staff?

Comment: In case of no (implicit) code to detect from the prose, probably choose **Unsalvageable**. But I'm not very active with reviewing from the queue.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319128/triage-review-queue-inconsistent-guidelines-for-requires-editing

Comment: Guys, I came from flagged duplicate q, and this still has that. Having a discussion tag, is it better to render "Some part of the question might have an answer here:"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [these posts] require the time and attention of the author.... Do I say that the question is "Unsalvageable", even though I believe it doesn't have too many issues and is in fact fixable?

Yes, "**Unsalvageable**" is the appropriate judgement for these posts.  If the post needs fixing and there is no reasonable way for the community to fix it, that's exactly what unsalvageable means in this context.  The label might appear to be harshly worded, but it's not as bad as it sounds.  There have been [past feature requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289738/suggestion-for-rewording-of-triage-review-guidance) to [relabel/clarify the specific text "unsalvageable"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278380/help-us-test-question-triage/278553#278553) into something less critical.

You can also leave a helpful comment to help communicate what is missing, but ultimately you need to review as unsalvageable (or skip).  This will cast (or flag) a close vote, which is not necessarily a bad thing.  The question might eventually be put on hold with a helpful message to help guide the author to make the necessary edits to their question.  This puts the ball in the author's court for them to fix the question by including the crucial details.  After that edit, their post will automatically be put into the reopen queue.

Everyone wins with this workflow. The question asker doesn't have to deal with bad answers that appear while the question was underspecified, but they still have a great chance of getting an answer to their problem once it is on-topic and answerable.  Answerers have more information to work with and can provide better answers.

Comment: Which sub-topic under "Unsalvageable" would you choose for these questions?

Comment: Anything in `Should be closed` especially `off-topic -> no MVCE (Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. )`  or `too broad`

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up guys, now I have a better understanding of triage as a whole.

Comment: If that's what it's supposed to mean, then I think "Unsalvageable" is not an appropriate word. Ok, the community cannot do anything out of it, but the post itself is not unsalvageable, OP can salvage it so by definition, it's not unsalvageable.