# Review Triage Queue - More Info needed from OP

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

I have been doing a few Triage Review, and have been wandering around Meta to understand how to sort the questions correctly.

I sometimes run into a question that looks clear, is written in good english and even has a sample code. But that is missing a important information to help OP solve his/her problem.

The last question I have been reviewing ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/12240079)) was almost like that. The guy did put the stacktrace of his application but did not put any code sample.

I commented the question, asked OP to add the sample code and sayed "Look OK". Is what I did correct ?

I know this has been discussed in a whole lot of questions on Meta but would adding a button saying "Waiting for OP to provide more details", and indicating which details are required to answer correctly be a good idea ?

I found [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278735/triage-how-to-vote-if-more-information-is-needed?rq=1) in the related questions. What happended to this idea ?

I don't understand, OK my question seems a duplicate of [Triage Review - Questions that require editing from the author [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320174/triage-review-questions-that-require-editing-from-the-author?lq=1), but that question is answered by saying let's put unsalvageable. Then it is considered as already answered in another post that says let's add "Should Be Improved" button...

Comment: If the question needed important code to be *complete* then it wasn't really OK. I'd probably add the comment and then "Skip".

Comment: I found [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278735/triage-how-to-vote-if-more-information-is-needed?rq=1) in the related section. What happenend to "Should Be Improved" ?

Comment: TBH...I don't know.

Comment: The review was probably: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/12240079

Comment: Looks like it went away. - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320174/triage-review-questions-that-require-editing-from-the-author?lq=1 Unsalvagable is the new Needs Improvement.

Comment: @AndrewMedico thanks, I updated it.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes but that post is linked to another question that has a different answer...

Comment: The 'other' question is much older. They are duplicates but one is more up to date than the other,

Comment: Ok then, I'll go with that one... Thanks