# How to handle a post, which only can improved by the author?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage, help-improvement

I often see posts in the Help and Improvement queue (HIQ), which only can improved by the author. How should I handle such a post?

I tried "question is very low quality", but the post was back in HIQ within a few minutes.

I couldn't find an answer to this question. All I could found is, that such a post should not be in the HIQ, see:

- [Is there a guide for the Triage queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674)
- [Triage Review Queue - Inconsistent guidelines for "Requires Editing"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319128/triage-review-queue-inconsistent-guidelines-for-requires-editing)
- [Triage Review - Questions that require editing from the author](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320174/triage-review-questions-that-require-editing-from-the-author)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong - the Triage reviewers are doing it wrong, though they might be thrown off guard by [this problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319128/triage-review-queue-inconsistent-guidelines-for-requires-editing). They should select <kbd>Unsalvageable</kbd> and depending on the actual problem with the question, an appropriate reason like 'Too broad' or 'MCVE required'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; the posts should not be in the H&I queue, and as already explained, it was caused by faulty reviews earlier down the line.

All you can do is click <kbd>Skip</kbd> and move on  to the next one. The queue  still contains plenty of post that require editing skill.

Don't forget to check the full list of everything that needs editing, including the appropriateness of the tags. This answer is particularly helpful whether you are a native speaker or not: [Advice for non-native English speakers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/4370109).

Sometimes, for a really bad one, you can click `question is very low quality`; but often that is not appropriate. Sometimes you can click on the `link` button and flag some other flaw. However, most times, just <kbd>Skip</kbd>.

Comment: If everyone follows your advice, and uses `Skip`, will the question ever leave the H&I queue?