# Is a good looking question enough reason to flag it as "Looks OK" In triage

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

I have recently gained access to reviewing Triage and the other  500 rep queues. I've been doing quite a few in the last 3 days as a result of that. Now the point of triage is to determine wether a question is good enough or needs editing.

Personally, I have no clue about a good few of tags on SO. So for instance in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9891505) question I have no practical knowledge of the matter whatsoever, but the question looks good and well formatted.

In this case is it enough to flag it as "Looks OK" or should I skip these?

Comment: If flowcharts help you take a look at [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278461/triage-gray-areas-what-should-we-do-when-the-question-is-borderline/278499#278499)

Comment: Related, though about the suggested-edits-queue: [There is no shame in using “Skip”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip)

Comment: There's also [a guide for Triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-triage/295674) that you might find useful.

Comment: Thank you guys, these have been very helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I am unsure I use skip. For any of the queues, we can't be expert on everything. There's enough users here to cover all the areas of expertise.

So if you even have to ask... skip

Answer (score 4):

Even good looking questions might still be [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696168/curious-about-the-implementation-of-caseinsensitivecomparator/31696231#31696231), or miss essential information. If you have a bit of experience in the matter, you are more likely to notice such cases.

As the Triage queue has a steady supply of new questions coming in, you can definitely skip them and pay more attention to those questions which are actually in your area of expertise.