# I worry that ChatGPT answers could currently be too tricky for use in review audits

Tags: discussion, review-audits, chatgpt

I just got [Late Answers Queue review item #33495800](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/33495800), which used [a now-deleted ChatGPT-generated answer, a/11107541](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74699440/11107541) as a review audit.

Since it was an audit, comments were hidden. There was a comment saying that the answer where someone had sniffed it out as being written by ChatGPT, but I couldn't see it until *after* I passed the audit. And I'm guessing that not all deleted-for-ChatGPT answers will have such comments on them.

I worry that this kind of thing can trip up reviewers (who aren't highly aware of the ChatGPT situation and haven't built up a sense for telltale ChatGPT signs) for [some of the the very reasons that ChatGPT is banned (at the time of this writing)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541): It writes in an authoritative style with proper spelling and grammar such that the many people/reviewers without enough subject-matter-knowledge/expertise to easily know whether it's *wrong* right off the bat will think it's probably right, and even people with subject-matter-expertise could take a while to verify the correctness.

If I wasn't so aware of the ChatGPT situation, having followed the meta posts and official announcements, and having gained some experience spotting such answers and learning the telltale signs from searching for ChatGPT posts when the flood started, I don't think I would have been able to know that I should have custom-flagged for ChatGPT or commented for suspicion of ChatGPT, linking to the ChatGPT policy page.

I don't think many people have even seen [this MSO post on what to do if one suspects an answer is ChatGPT-generated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421988/11107541). At the time of this writing, it has under 1k views.

Possible routes forward I thought of:

- Give clear guidance to reviewers on how to spot possible ChatGPT answers (but I'm not sure if we really want to do this right now, since we seem to want to avoid doing that to avoid helping ChatGTP-answerers learn how to avoid detection), and tell them [what to do when they are confident that they have found such an answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421988/11107541).

  I'd suggest this guidance to be given somewhere visible in the review UI. I'm not sure if [the review guidance FAQ post on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180031/997587) is an appropriate place, since [ChatGPT policies are currently set per-site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385002/997587).
- Somehow prevent ChatGPT-flagged answers from being used in review audits.

Thoughts?

Comment: I mean fully agreed, but it is not like the existing eligible posts are so great for audits. They're automatically picked so it'll automatically go wrong. This just feeds into the existing trouble, bad bookkeeping leads to bad audits.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I agree that ChatGPT answers should not be used as audits. A large part of the issue with ChatGPT content is how much the generated content appears (on the surface) to be a genuine answer. That said, there really isn't much we can do to stop this from happening now that it has been chosen as an audit.

The system sees [this specific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74699440/15497888) as a valid audit candidate because it is (1) deleted and (2) has a [Very Low Quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420) (VLQ) flag which was marked helpful. That's it; that's all that is necessary to make the post eligible to become a review audit for [LA](https://stackoverflow.com/review) or [LQA](https://stackoverflow.com/review).

The good news is that the vast majority of these ChatGPT answers are deleted with either only a mod flag or removed as part of a moderator investigation. Any posts that do not have a helpful standard flag on the post (VLQ/[NAA](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420)) will not be eligible audit candidates. For this reason, these types of audits should not be too widespread. There's perhaps a handful of posts among thousands that are eligible to become audits.

The bad news is that we (as moderators) don't really have any good options to stop this post from being used as an audit now that it has been chosen. Undeleting the post would stop that post from being used as an audit, but that would go against our current policy. We can't change the fact that there's a helpful flag on the post now that it has been marked helpful. We could lock the post (or flag it as [R/A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-rude-or-abusive-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-wor)), but that seems excessive just to remove it from the audit pool.

So, for the moment, we'll have to continue to handle these audits on a case-by-case basis.

---

There are a few things we can do *before* the post is deleted. As moderators, we can decline the VLQ/NAA flags before handling the mod flag to prevent these from becoming audits, but it can be difficult to make sure that such flags are always declined before removing the answer (for any number of reasons).

When reviewing answers in LA or LQA, reviewers can flag for moderator attention instead of voting to delete posts that are generated by ChatGPT. If the post is deleted from review the NAA/VLQ flags will be marked helpful, which will in turn make it an audit candidate. Please flag it for moderator attention so that we can handle the post (and the user).

Comment: concerning the last paragraph, I've been seeing a noticeable amount of chatgpt in the LQA queue, and the unfortunate thing is that handling of chatgpt flags right now is bottlenecked by [heuristic approval](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/391990/997587). even ones I've flagged a while ago. I just skip / flag if I haven't flagged already...

Answer (score -4):

"many people/reviewers without enough subject-matter-knowledge/expertise to easily know whether it's wrong right off the bat will [fail the audit]" is a **good** thing.

Reviewers facing a topic outside their area of expertise should use the *Skip* button liberally, and never click *Looks Ok*.

Reviewers facing a topic within their area of expertise who don't have the time to actually assess whether the answer is correct should also use *Skip*, not *Looks Ok*.

It's not like the audit requires you to determine that the answer is ChatGPT-generated and click "Recommend Deletion".  That's a good outcome if you do it, but skipping, editing, and commenting all will also pass the audit.  The only thing that will fail is clicking *Looks Ok*, which indeed meant you weren't paying attention (to the answer and to your own limits).

Comment: Nowhere in https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-late-answers do I see indication that reviewers of first answers are expected to be able to judge factual correctness of answers. I **do** see clear indication that reviewers are expected to either judge whether a late answer post is an attempt to answer the question, or skip if unsure due to lack of familiarity with the topic: "_However, in other cases it may require specific knowledge of the topic. If you’re unsure whether the answer actually attempts to answer the question, use the “Skip” option._"

Comment: Nowhere in https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-first-answers do I see indication that reviewers of first answers are expected to be able to judge factual correctness of answers. I **do** see clear indication that reviewers are expected to judge whether the _form_ of the post is a good fit for the Stack Exchange model: grammar, spelling, formatting, being an attempt to answer the question, not a duplicate answer, not link-only, not spam, not rude or abusive.

Comment: We don't expect mods to be able to take action on flags about the factual correctness of posts. I don't see why _reviewers_ should be expected of that either.

Comment: @user: [Is a good looking question enough reason to flag it as "Looks OK" In triage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308278/103167)

Comment: [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/103167)

Comment: note to other skimmers: those are respectively for the triage and primarily the suggested edit queues. the specific problem in the traige post is something that can be solved by using the tag filters, and I see suggested _edits_ as a different problem than reviewing supposedly original content.