# Review Suspension: ChatGPT/LLM Audits

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension, first-answers

Well, I screwed up! I managed to fail two audits in as many months, and received a review suspension as a result. Both of these were valid audits—the responses were deemed to have been generated by ChatGPT, which I failed to recognize at the time of review:

1. [Evaluating forward references with typing.get_type_hints in Python for a class defined inside another method/class](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/34519871)
2. [How can I add space between elements in JavaScript (React)?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/34717321)

**I understand and accept my mistake, and commit to being more diligent about evaluating suspiciously articulate posts, and especially from new contributors.** A lot of ChatGPT are really obvious to me, but these two obviously slipped under my radar, and demonstrate that I need to be more skeptical in looking out for this class of posts.

The second one, which I failed today, is especially egregious since a) it includes the suspiciously ChatGPTesque phrase, "Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this", and b) even if I failed to recognize that, the post merited editing for formatting, so "Looks OK" was just plain lazy of me.

Despite this, I'd like to request having my review privileges reenabled. My overall track record as a reviewer remains positive—I provided ~3,750 reviews in that period, including dozens of successful audits—and the issue here is well understood. I'd like to get back to contributing to the queues. If not, of course, I understand, given that this was my failure to correctly identify generated answers.

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: With posts that smell like spam—such as enthusiastic recommendations for novel libraries or alternate services—I often check the reviewer's history to see if there's a pattern of such posts to support the suspicion. Taking a similar approach to posts from new contributors who show far better spelling, formatting, and explanations than most new contributors might help weed out those serially posting generated answers, but which aren't otherwise obvious. It's a bit of a perverse heuristic—being suspicious of otherwise laudable contributions—but that's the world we find ourselves in!

Comment: Another example of how LLM messes up our community. Sorry for you and I wholeheartedly support your appeal. Meanwhile, maybe treat this as an opportunity to join and support the moderator strike :)

Comment: Your reviewing is very good in general - I've lifted the suspension

Comment: In both cases, the issue was that a Very Low Quality flag was marked helpful by the answer being deleted.  I remain convinced that the VLQ flag's existence causes more significantly trouble than benefit.

Comment: I don't understand why the second post is ChatGPT one. The first is evident, but the second, I could write something like this

Comment: @Elikill58 I agree it's not an easy one. There's this typical GPT pattern, though: an intro like "To do xy, you can [...]" followed by "Here's how you can do xy" followed by a list of code blocks. Usually it's then followed by "additionaly" or an equivalent, but not in this one. I would have clicked "skip" because it's not an easy one to prove (despite the patterns I've mentioned).

Comment: You'll probably want to read the answer post to [I worry that ChatGPT answers could currently be too tricky for use in review audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422338/11107541)

Comment: @Rob: Thank you very much; I sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: @JeremyCaney all the more reason to always open up the source post in a separate tab to get the complete picture. You *shouldn't have to*, but if you stick to what you shouldn't have to do then curation on this site sucks big time.

Comment: I am confused by the second one. It is a First Answer review but the user has been a member for 12+ years and has plenty of answers.

Comment: @user10186832 - “Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this” then providing a list is common ChatGPT output. There is absolutely no way that answer wasn’t generated by ChatGPT, it matches the output of ChatGPT, almost exactly.

Comment: @Elikill58 "Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:" trips flags for me, FWIW.