# Would a dedicated ChatGPT/AI flag be a viable solution to long response times to other flags? What can be done instead if not?

Tags: discussion, flags, ai-generated-content

I have seen the post [New flag for ChatGPT answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388587/1377755) which suggests adding a dedicated flag for AI-generated content. The answer touches on the fact that Plagiarism flags were added for a specific purpose and have specific criteria for use, and can be filtered by moderators. But otherwise, the answer does not mention the issue of a high number of AI-flags delaying response times to other flags.

According to [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/427092/16217248), the 'lion's share' of custom mod flags are AI-generated content related flags. However, since they are in the same queue and not distinguished from other mod flags, I have experienced that the massive quantity of AI-related flags are severely delaying response times to other flags. Most of my most recent non-AI-related mod flags are from months ago and they are still pending. However, the answer says that they 'don't think it's practical to request a specific flag at this time.'

My thought is that distinguishing AI flags from other flags can improve response times to other issues since they can be in a separate queue. However, to what extent is this true? Otherwise, what can be done to improve response times to other custom flags, since currently, they're being drowned out by AI-flags?

Comment: It seems intuitively obvious that "yes" is the answer, so much so such that I'm wondering why this is being asked. A better question is "what changes would result in better response times from moderators to 'in need of moderator intervention' flags?" A sub-question that addresses part of that issue could be "what's the right way to allow moderators to be able to filter 'in need of moderator intervention' flags?" While creating a new flag type for suspected AI-generated content would help the issue, I'm not convinced it's the best solution, but it might be the expedient solution.

Comment: would creating a new flag for this somehow clear up the backlog of flags that can't be handled?

Comment: @KevinB Not immediately, but it would reduce the influx of new backlog.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but isn't the answer to a backlog of flags for any reason simply to promote additional users to moderator privilges?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk if the problem was lack of hands, sure. In this case the problem is the company approved heuristics aren't allowing these flags to be handled, so, that won't help.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk continuing on Kevin's point, see second half of https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/394774/997587

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk "simply to promote additional users to moderator privilges" Maybe there aren't that many qualified users willing to not only get the moderator privileges but also spending time working with these privileges. You surely cannot simply take any user and give him/her these privileges. That might speed up handling of non-AI-related flags, but the outcomes might not be sufficiently good.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution It is not the same issue. the strike was because mods were basically not allowed to moderate AI at all, except in most blatantly obvious cases. Now, there is heuristics that should be used to verify user is posting AI, but the process for approving actionable heuristics is painfully slow. As result, there are thousands beyond obvious AI posts on sites that cannot be dealt with under currently approved heuristics. As more heuristics gets approved, more posts could be handled and that is also one of the reasons why AI flags are not being declined and wait.

Comment: Just because some AI posts have been unhandled for months does not mean they are not detected and will not be handled in the future. Anyone thinking they are getting away with their AI posting are just deluding themselves.

Comment: It sounds like the only viable solution is to let hired staff deal with it. Or otherwise get rid of the policy. All of this under the assumption that the company cares about the quality of their own products, an assumption which I admittedly can present no recent evidence for.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar "...there are thousands beyond obvious AI posts on sites that cannot be dealt with under currently approved heuristics..." I would argue that for all practical purposes there is no difference to the situation that elicited the strike except for a promise that it will change in the future. If you do not trust much in the future, it looks remarkably similar if not identical for all practical purposes. I mean that there is little to no practical difference between "don't do that" and "don't do that before I tell you that you can do that". May change in the future.

Comment: @Lundin The whole issue started because staff thought moderators are removing non AI posts. As far as the company leadership is concerned, they don't care if sites have AI posts, their metrics is not about quality, but quantity and they definitely don't think long term. If AI moderation is left to the company, then we can all pack and go home. Not to mention, that in order to deal with AI you first need to be able to recognize all kinds of AI. That is something community and moderators collectively can do much better than few employees who would also have other responsibilities besides AI.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution Well, for practical purposes, you can say that situation is similar, but still there is a huge difference between actively preventing moderation and heuristics approval process going slowly. So, while we are approaching the point of no return, there is still a lot of work going on and that situation can improve soon enough.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar The point of no return was reached when the company stopped giving a shit about the community, quality of content, and long-term goals of the site.

Comment: If we actually want the company to take action on this, it seems like the only way to make them care is to adopt a policy of using any heuristics the company has not reviewed within a reasonable timeframe (say 2 months) until the company actively vetos them with evidence, rather than waiting for the company to approve them. That would actually incentivize the company to try to streamline and prioritize heuristics reviews, rather than the current process where they are incentivized to actively push them back.