# Is the flag ban of damocles waiting for me; or am I just wrong with triage queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

I find myself flagging a lot more posts mostly through the use of the triage queue. As a matter of fact, I flag so much posts I wonder if I'm doing this right.

Until now I've been pretty on topic with those flags and have very few refused, however, my "moderator attention" flags number only goes up.

**Are we overwhelming <del>mods</del> community with these flags?** I can't be the only one who started flagging questions a lot more.

I believe in my flags, but may I have enough of them waiting for moderator attention so that I could be banned from flagging, were I to fail many of them in a short amount of time?

I guess there won't be a significant enough increase in the processing of flags for ban to happen like this. Or would there?

Comment: You're flags gonna be triaged :)

Comment: The close vote queue is huge, much bigger than you're actually allowed to see. It can take a while for questions that get a single close flag or vote to actually get closed (if ever). For example: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252586/regarding-the-stack-overflow-close-review-queue/252600#252600

Comment: Diamond moderators don't handle close flags. The community (the part with close vote privileges) does.

Comment: @Martijn And what about non-diamond moderators? Do they deal with the close votes? ;)

Comment: @skuntsel: Stack Exchange is built on *community moderation*, so everyone is, by degrees, a moderator. I was trying to be explicit that those that have been elected to be moderators (with a diamond next to their name) do not handle the flags, the community moderators do.

Comment: @Martijn You took pun as a request to disclose information on SO's notion of moderation. Didn't mean that at all.

Comment: @skuntsel: the confusion pops up from time to time, and it wasn't clear enough to me that you meant to pun there. Sorry if I doused your pun in cold water!

Comment: +1 just for the title, that might just be the most interesting/amusing question title I've seen on SE... 'flag ban of damocles' may just become my new handle...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I guess there won't be a significant enough increase in the processing of flags for ban to happen like this. Or would there?

Considering these are close flags, this would only be remotely plausible if you happen to have a majority of these flags declined and with few to no other helpful flags.  Close flags are rejected if the community votes to keep a question open.

Other than that, they're not at all bothersome to diamond moderators since they do not show up in that flag queue.  These flags only add to the community close queue, which is already massive.

As for myself, I still have over 300 of these flags pending, many of which were sitting around for at least a year.  You're definitely not alone.