# Review queue updates

Tags: discussion, review-queues, top-bar, announcement

We are actively working on top bar improvements, many of which are a part of bringing the new top bar to the Stack Exchange network sites. Several of the changes are relevant to SO. As such, you should [read the full update here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/new-top-bar-next-steps-and-response-to-feedback).

Specifically, I wanted to call out the following issues which have received attention here on Meta SO.

> ### [Review queue icon sucks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355236/the-new-review-icon-isnt-an-improvement)
>
> **Concern:** The review queue icon doesn't look anything like what I'd expect. It isn't recognizable. (note: this is actually a hold over from SO feedback)
>
> **Status:** [status-planned](/questions/tagged/status-planned)
>
> **Explanation:** We are happy to change this icon to one that works better for everyone. We ran a survey for people to pick their top two favorite icons. Over 600 people participated. We are doing some additional design review on the top two candidates and will announce the results soon.
>
> ### [Review queue false positives](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300864/354333)
>
> **Concern:** The review queue shouldn't "light up" or have the red dot when there are no items to review.
>
> **Status:** [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)
>
> **Explanation:** We've squashed some bugs with the new design, but probably have a few more to deal with. We will continue on our bug stomping journey.
>
> ### [Add labels to icons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300872/354333)
>
> **Concern:** Still, the icons aren't as recognizable as they should be. But if you add labels below them they would be. Please add labels.
>
> **Status:** [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)
>
> **Explanation:** There is no room for legible labels in the current design. The font would have to be so small that it is arguable if it would help many people. (The [example posted to meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opoIr.png) cheated a bit by changing "achievements" to the much shorter "awards".)

Comment: Was a little concerned with the "just take this survey!" link, but the options look good. Some of them seem like improvements to me at least.

Comment: Icons: 1. Open notepad, 2. Discuss agenda, 3. Enable hamburger menu, 4. Approve something, 5. Go racing, 6. Let's talk stapler, baby! I think the fourth comes closest...

Comment: obligatory reference to [best review icon suggestion I've seen so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350836/please-change-the-review-icon-back-to-a-text-link/351081#comment482625_350836)

Comment: I say we go for something like this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351081/7733026

Comment: I'm missing the review items count on the top bar.

Comment: @Joe Firend
Awesome! It's great to see You guys keep constantly improving and taking feedback into consideration! Keep up the good work :)

Comment: @JamesDouglas Please don't start polishing turds.

Comment: Labels: How about showing a tooltip when hovering one of the icons?

Comment: @idmean We currently show tooltips.

Comment: while spending so much efforts on questionable UX changes, how hard it would be to find an hour or two of dev time to address this simple request: **[Looking for stats on how frequency of skip actions correlates with amount of reviews done by user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351269/839601)**? I ask because it is closely related to the problem you're trying to address, one of the awful attrition of reviewers - "...many users find it difficult to work in review queue... even after substantial amount of reviews, many users still fail to discover a way to work productively..."

Comment: User [this userstyle](https://userstyles.org/styles/162940/stackoverflow-header-buttons-text) for Firefox addon Stylish to fix.

Answer (score 19):

Small comment regarding shapes: three of those icons have three horizontal lines

[image: three suggested review icons]

To me this clashes with the Stack Exchange icon. With either one, we'll have two adjacent icons containing three lines. The second icon is the worst here, it almost mirrors the Stack Exchange icon:

[image]

Comment: Valid point. The checkmark helps a lot, I think. I actually kind of like the flag icon, because it's clear and completely unambiguous. Someone on MSE made the argument that flagging and reviewing are two completely separate actions, but I'm not sure I see it that way. Flags are (generally) how you put an item into review, so you're basically just reviewing flagged posts. Makes sense to me.

Comment: @CodyGray - I didn't like the flag icon at first and didn't vote for it, but it grew on me over the past long hours. Some flags do end up on the queue, so it does make sense. It has a distinct shape. It also feels like the user is receiving more responsibility - the user  is *helping resolve flags*, not *completing tasks*. I may be overthinking this though.

Comment: Reading these comments it might be nice to turn the flag red in case there is a overflowing queue.

Comment: The middle one looks more like a chat bubble to me.

Comment: Wow I did not understand the flag at all. I thought it was the worst because I couldn't make heads or tails of it. Seeing the comments here it makes more sense now

Answer (score 7):

I feel an urge to quoting the @canon answer at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351081/4758255 about the review:

> Go for a hybrid, imo. When accompanied by an icon, the text doesn't
>   have to be as big as the first-class links.
>
> [image: icon text hybrid links]

The current review icon looks like an edit icon. Here an edit icon (from fontawesome) vs review icon (SO):

Edit icon:

[image]

Review icon:

[image]

I don't get any information from current review list except red alert. Take a look at previous review list vs current review list below:

**previous review list from [Please change the review icon back to a text link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350836/please-change-the-review-icon-back-to-a-text-link):**

[image]

**current review details:**

[image]

The current review list feel so bland. It didn't encourage me to do the review.

Please bring back the previous review list.

Quoting from Steve Krug, Don't Make Me Think: A Common Sense Approach to Web Usability book:

> Designers love subtle cues, because subtlety is one of the traits of
>   sophisticated design. But Web users are generally in such a hurry that
>   they routinely miss subtle cues.
>
> .
>
> Your objective should always be to eliminate instructions entirely by
>   making everything self-explanatory, or as close to it as possible.
>   When instructions are absolutely necessary, cut them back to a bare
>   minimum.

Comment: I think it's better to split your answer, that way people can vote for some parts of your answer, and the SE team gets feedback on a smaller part of the navigation, so they can perform more directed fixes