# New Reviews Icon?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, top-bar

It seems the review icon has changed again. Have we rolled out a [new review icon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357621/review-queue-updates), or is this in testing?

[image]

The new icon bears some resemblance to the adjacent hamburger, but I think the check mark is a big improvement over the previous pencilly thingy:

[image]

Comment: This came as a surprise to me. Somebody at SO finally woke up to make this change

Comment: You answered your own question with your first sentence.

Comment: Looks like right bottom angle is missing

Comment: I like hamburgers.

Comment: It's the first time that I upvoted and voted to close a question at the same time.

Comment: new review icon... but still a buggy red dot i think

Comment: @AntoinePelletier: Could you be a bit more specific? Maybe in an answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly).

Comment: They changed the review icon about [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/349538) after changing the top bar on all sites.

Comment: @JonEricson ok i just saw the post... red dot is because : "it’s been at least an hour since you clicked on the review icon". Honestly I would remove this condition, or just add a yellow dot if there is no red dot in any review queue. Because i often see a red dot on the menu, once i click : no red dot in any queue... it's way too confusing. Why a red dot straight in the menu if there is nothing urgent in my queues ?

Comment: Does anyone have a link to the old icon? I can't remember it lol

Comment: Here's what the blog post says about the red dot.  It sounds like a great idea but seems broken...  

You’ll see the indicator is turned on:

if any review queue has a red dot (explained below) and
if it’s been at least an hour since you clicked on the review icon.

Comment: @brett, Added image of old icon.

Comment: @StephenRauch Ahhhh I remember it now, and agree, MUCH improved :)

Comment: This looks good I also liked it! The tick thing!

Comment: Seems broken, in that it seems to be using an OR to turn the dot red, rather than an AND, on the listed conditions.  Or maybe it just doesn't refresh state very fast...?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Yes, it's a new review icon. It is available to all. Think of it as an early Christmas gift (or a [white elephant gift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_elephant_gift_exchange) if you don't love it). This is a variation of the winning icon from the poll we ran during the testing of the top bar on the network sites ([see this post for the mention](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/new-top-bar-is-live)).

Comment: I was hoping for a small mushroom cloud, but I suppose this will have to do

Comment: @Machavity [Like this one?](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/22/f5/86/22f58661f4de99f50842b0d7ea332e27.jpg)

Comment: As per https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359971/the-new-review-icon - thanks for implementing this. It's a huge improvement.

Comment: The bottom dark horizontal line of the icon is fatter than the others. Yuk. Also, ironically, there are now 4 horizontal lines yet the stackexchange icon supposedly could not manage 4 horizontal lines & had to be reduced to 3. Ok--4 plus a tail. But the new review icon has that fat bottom line.

Comment: What fat bottom line? Are you talking about the gray area underneath the white lines?

Comment: Any chance we'll be able to get a functional, reliable red dot? I've complained about this to no avail, as have others.

Comment: @jhpratt As identified in the [monthly DAG update for November](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/302969/354333), we are committed to fixing this. It works quite well for some people and less so for others. There are several issues and scenarios to address. We will be taking them on by one. Unfortunately, we didn't get too far this month, but we will take another wack at it in December.

Comment: @jhpratt Is it possible that I have a buggy red dot because i'm in between 2 step of privilege : IF i had access to all queue, i would see where the red dot is INSIDE the menu, but since i have access to only three type of queue, i can't see it ? Also...  i think the timer is superfluous.

Comment: @JonEricson about my previous comment ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier That is exactly the problem. We are going to adjust how the indicator works so that you only see the red dot if a queue you have access to is red.

Comment: Thanks ! Really appreciated.