# The new review icon

Tags: discussion, design

I like it - it's much nicer than the old one.

[image: New Review Icon]

Good job :)

That's all.

<sub>I'm not really sure if these sorts of posts are the done thing here, but I figured some positive feedback is warranted, whereas usually meta seems to be full of complaining/suggestions.</sub>

Comment: I agree. The old icon was incredibly arcane. This one uses instantly recognizable motifs such as lines on a rectangle representing a list/document and a checkmark representing appraisal/validation. (I have no idea if I should post this as an answer, just like how you're unsure if this post belongs.)

Comment: Looks like it's already attracted a close vote. Ah well, I don't care. I still think the guys deserve props for fixing it. Maybe I needed to give it a freehand red circle...

Comment: Not really @StephenRauch - that seems to be more complaining that is changed than thanking them for doing so...

Comment: What? I wrote that question, you will note that I actually complemented the new design.  In fact I see no complaint in the question at all.

Comment: Hmm, rereading it I can see it that way. I just was drawn to `It seems the review icon has changed again.` and `bears some resemblance to the adjacent hamburger`. But you're right, the overall tone is more positive than I thought.

Comment: Glad you like it - I'll pass this along to the team! And yes, free-hand red circles are expected.