# Stats to compare efficiency of close votes cast on weekends vs weekdays

Tags: support, review-queues, vote-to-close, statistics

Related: [Raise the limits on down/close votes at weekends, (and especially Sundays)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365082/839601)

This request is kind of follow-up / complement for above. I would want to get comparative statistics on efficiency of close votes cast on weekends vs weekdays by active voters (by those who cast over 20-30 votes a day average):

- average number of answers and what percent ends unanswered on questions they voted to close (since the purpose of closing is to prevent answers this looks like most straightforward measure of efficiency)
- percentage of questions that end up closed / deleted

My understanding of the issue discussed in related request is, it is focused on recent questions, that is stats should probably be limited to questions posted the same day or two before vote was cast.

<sup>And anyway I would prefer old questions to be ignored (posted more than 60 days or something like that before the vote was cast) - because it looks difficult to meaningfully relate such questions to weekends / weekdays dynamics.</sup>

---

Alternatively or additionally, I am interested in similar stats that are more directly related to [functioning of close queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365361/839601) which are probably easier to obtain.

Specifically, I would want to compare the following for the questions that enter the queue on weekends vs weekdays:

- what percent of questions ages away from the queue
- average number of answers on these questions  and what percent ends unanswered

I expect these stats to help us better understand whether there is an issue and if yes then how much it is worth worrying about.

Comment: *by those who cast over 20-30 votes a day average* ... can't you just ask those 5 users?

Comment: @rene of course not, these folks forget what they did the moment after casting :)

Comment: Did someone ask a question?  :)

Comment: it's a weekday today @MartinJames - any question will be closed immediately ;)

Comment: It's probably terrible to be honest. Close votes age so quickly, it is probably just exacerbated by the weekend. I know a decent amount of close votes are wasted, unfortunately. Knowing the exact percent of wasted close votes may be disheartening, regardless of its weekend or not.

Comment: @TravisJ for questions having less than 100 views (probably vast majority of those voted to close) expiration takes [14 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120902/165773), to me it doesn't look too quickly to be fair

Comment: @gnat - The main issue is that from my experience only the newest close votes show in the queue unless you start to use filters or alternative approaches. This means that while the votes may expire after 14 days, they are factually unreachable far before that. If you take a 2 or 3 day hit on the chance of having the post closed it is possible that the line for not being reached is already hit.

Comment: @TravisJ agree, this could possibly be an issue. Particularly on weekends when there are less reviewers, so that a day or two later weekend votes are prioritized too low in the queue due to age hit

Comment: Doesn't the close vote queue show the oldest questions first to the reviewers? Shouldn't it?

Comment: @Nisarg details of sorting in the queue [are explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199912/165773); in brief system favors more recent questions and more reviews