# Close voters call to arms: let's make this September welcoming

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close, clean-up

["It is September once again... and once again students are asking their homework problems..."](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/31260)

How about we help site newcomers learn to properly ask questions by spending few minutes in [review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/165773) and voting to close inappropriate ones more quickly. You can think of this as a kind of lightweight complement to various educational, welcoming, and mentoring initiatives that appear to be so popular of late.

Here are two queue filters that seem to be easiest to find and review troublesome questions: **[too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-closereason=TooBroad)** and **[unclear](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-closereason=Unclear)**. Of these two filters, the first one feels slightly more efficient to me, but I wouldn't bet on that - so I guess it's really up to you to pick.

<sup>For those having more time, another queue filter is probably most useful from the asker's perspective, because the custom close reasons tend to provide very accurate and easy-to-follow guidance: **[off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-closereason=OffTopic)**. I abstain from recommending it to everyone (nor do I frequently use it myself) because in my experiments it appeared to be noticeably slower than other filters listed above (and just in case if you wonder - no, I am not going to [waste my time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314348/165773) asking the dev team to fix that).</sup>

I am not going to load this suggestion with "success metrics", "progress indicators", "milestone definitions", and other stuff like that, because, per my recollection of a prior, somewhat similar [effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251489/839601), it didn't look particularly useful.

- If you just make a few short visits to the close vote queue for a couple of days, that would be cool.

At first I was going to end this suggestion with a lengthy explanation of how the timely closing of inappropriate questions is helpful to new users - both askers and answerers. It really is, and if I posted this a year or two ago, I would maybe provide a thorough explanation of why that is so, with proper reasoning, examples, and references to other meta discussions, etc.

But then I thought, no - today things are different and what I really want *now* is for us to somehow balance various misleading ideas and suggestions about the [welcoming](/questions/tagged/welcoming) effort that seem to be spreading around lately. So be it.

---

As an optional supplement, a few productivity tips for those willing to participate:

- Skip review when you doubt that the question is worth closing ([there is no shame in that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252195/839601)).
   
  <sup>When I am particularly short on time I even fall back to blindly skipping all questions that are longer than 6-7 lines. I'm sure that this way I miss some close-worthy ones, but it speeds up things so much and, which is critically important, it keeps me certain about the votes I do cast, because I read and understand the question entirely. Even though there are other voters to keep things going right despite my occasional mistakes, I don't accept urgency as an excuse for wrong close votes.</sup>
- Skip and avoid wasting time on questions that look like they are worth leaving open.
   
  <sup>Proper decision on these tends to take more time and (most importantly) these are likely to expire off the queue and stay open without your involvement anyway. (if you think this also means that many close-worthy questions expire and stay open, keeping their askers unaware of the problem, well, [it is indeed so](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293457/839601))</sup>.
- If you fail an audit, try to slow down, or better yet, take a short rest.
   
  <sup>I know there are slippery audits and I always [manually correct](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773) the audited post if it feels wrong, so that it won't trick the next reviewer - no matter if I fail or pass. But when I fail, that is also always an indication that I am not in good enough shape and need to do something about myself to improve focus (or take a rest if I can't). I have done several tens of thousands of reviews, and treating audit failures as signs that I need to be more attentive has been extremely helpful.</sup>

Comment: I've been meaning to ask this a long time - but what are these "queues", and why would I (or anyone else) want to pay attention to them? I have been an SO user for a looong time - longer than my current account, and I simply cannot see the point.

Comment: @NeilButterworth They were an attempt to concentrate the efforts of users who want to help moderate, but there's still too much to do. Even a hundred teaspoons won't have much effect in a deluge.

Comment: @Josh But I do moderate - I often use up all my downvotes on the C++ tag which is the only one (well, C as well) that I feel expert enough to do so.  I just don't get this "queue" stuff.

Comment: Certainly, @NeilButterworth; I didn't mean to imply one couldn't moderate without using the queues.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I think this is best addressed in community FAQ at MSE: [What are the review queues, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/165773) I edited the post to refer the FAQ for readers who don't know

Comment: Also for reviewers, there is an userscript that adds keyboard shortcuts to the various options while reviewing https://github.com/rschrieken/stackoverflow-close-votes-shortcuts

Comment: "Skip and avoid wasting time on questions that look worth leaving open" - this improves one's own productivity, but doesn't do much for the overall productivity of the community - you're just pushing the work of reviewing the question to someone else (or everyone skips it, in which case it will probably just be shown to a whole bunch of people).

Comment: @Dukeling skip won't show it to more people, I checked it many times already. Reviews age away to the bottom of the queue very quickly, one that hasn't been touched for few hours drowns deep below under other reviews and expires without bothering anyone, that's why I explained it under the point in the post you refer to: "(most importantly) these are likely to expire off the queue and stay open without your involvement anyway". It is rather opposite, leave open vote will re-prioritize post back to the top of the queue where it will keep wasting reviewers attention and risking incorrect close

Comment: @gnat That makes it sound like the Leave Open and Skip buttons are broken (and they should possibly have their effects almost swapped around) and someone should post a feature request asking for it to be fixed (if one doesn't exist already). Or perhaps not the buttons themselves, but rather how things are prioritised in the queue.

Comment: @Dukeling what is really broken is not enough reviewers, as evidenced eg by [data provided by Shog here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252600/839601). The rest is more or less okay - I have some relatively minor reservations about how reviews are prioritized but overall approach to handling all three outcomes (close, leave open and skip) looks sane for last 3-4 years, I checked that many times

Comment: @gnat Well, you're advocating clicking Skip on a question if you think we should Leave it Open (and never click Leave Open?). If this is truly the most effective thing to do, that is not particularly sane. And if the question *does* end up getting enough views regardless, Skipping will make it more likely that the question gets closed, because there are no Leave Opens to cancel out the Closes (IIRC how things work). There are ways to address not having enough reviewers (other than trying to get more reviewers).

Comment: @Dukeling as I mentioned in prior comment root cause for the issues is there are not enough reviewers to handle things better. Skip in case like you describe is indeed a compromise but since we lack reviewers it just turns out work better than voting. If there were enough reviewers I would probably advise to do it differently

Comment: ...things you need to realize is, when you vote (from review) on a definitely close worthy question, this pushes it to the top of the queue and increases chances that other reviewers will get to it. If your evaluation / vote is correct this means question will be (deservedly) quicker closed

Comment: What exactly is the point of this question? Increase the amount of users doing reviews? Increase awareness about the queues? I'm pretty sure the majority of users that know about Meta's existence, also know about the queues' existence...

Comment: @Cerbrus it's right there, in the text: "If you just make a few short visits to the close vote queue for a couple of days, that would be cool." I meant to attract folks who usually abstain of reviewing to make a minor temporary effort. Another useful thing I didn't anticipate is that answers here shared couple time-saving suggestions

Comment: So, basically, a little review "event" to make a bit of a dent in the queue.

Comment: @Cerbrus basically yes (it's tagged [meta-tag:clean-up])

Comment: _"Aux armes, citoyens,
Formez vos bataillons,
Marchons, marchons !"_ etc etc

Comment: I'd like to help. I've got a C++ dup hammer. How can I only get C++ tagged duplicate flags in the close vote queue?

Comment: @YSC there you go - [queue filtered by c++](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/20975455?filter-tags=c%2b%2b) (folks interested in more details on how that works can refer this MSE post: [Allow direct linking to a filtered /review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209777/165773))

Comment: @YSC sorry my first link was only by tag and didn't have additional filter by duplicate close reason - here is corrected one: [c++ duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=c%2b%2b&filter-closereason=duplicate)

Comment: don't worry, the doc you linked was what I was really looking for ;)

Comment: @NeilButterworth - queue votes and *in the wild votes* are counted as different so you actually have about double the votes you think you have.

Answer (score 35):

You're missing another important class of questions, which need to be closed. Duplicates!  Yes, many new questions are flagged as duplicates and they need to be reviewed as well (there were 58 posts flagged as duplicate in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) yesterday). Troublesome questions that are too broad and unclear are certainly a problem as you mention, but duplicates are a problem too.

If you have a gold hammer in a tag, then please review [**the duplicates questions in that badge**](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-closereason=Duplicate). Don't let your gold hammer get corroded by leaving it in the open and doing nothing. Also, remember to hammer correct. With great power comes great responsibilities.

Unlike the other review queues, which need 4 other reviewers to close, just one gold badge holder can complete a review by voting to close duplicates.

Comment: Bhagrav, good point. Though I excluded duplicates _intentionally_. :( Here I was primarily asking for help from folks who don't usually review and I tried to make it easy for them. This unfortunately [leaves duplicates off](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151994/165773): "Based on my experience... duplicates review went slower (much slower) than the rest..." (please notice how I also abstained of recommending off-topic for similar considerations, despite custom close reasons being so helpful for askers)

Comment: I figured that out while reading your question @gnat, but hey, there are many gold badge users amongst the folks who don't usually review. If atleast a couple of them start to review after seeing this, then it's a win for us. (and I completely agree that too broad and unclear are the easiest ones to start with, especially for people who have just earned 3k rep and testing waters)

Comment: They do need to be closed. But handling duplicates takes more time, because you must do the search for duplicates that the OP neglected to do.

Comment: @Raedwald, you don't need to do the searching. Others would have searched the duplicate already. You would just need to judge if they've chosen it correct or not. You'll get a tab while reviewing, where you can see the target post.

Comment: The selected duplicate target is rarely the best target. I have a good badge, and so must be more careful.

Comment: Interesting @Raedwald, when I review in Python, 90% of the time they would have chosen the correct target. Perhaps the issue is with larger tags or the issue is just with [java]? Someone from [js] can probably confirm the theory.

Comment: @BhargavRao Problem exists in [c++], too. I don't have any hard stats at hand, but the correct suggestions that linger around don't make up close to 90%. Probably because the clear oned are usually handled pretty fast in that tag.

Comment: Uh, @BaummitAugen, C++ is a smaller tag than Python, so my theory falls apart. I guess another theory can be that python is better organized with a set of canonicals to which we can dupe.

Comment: I'm pretty sure gold doesn't corrode...

Comment: @OrangeDog gold can get tarnished...

Comment: @BhargavRao So you're saying the golden hammers are cheaper impure gold?

Comment: @AndyJ, unfortunately pure gold is too soft to make hammers, so we need to use the industrial gold (18 karat gold)...

Comment: @BhargavRao Ah! And the constant use gets rid of the tarnish ... makes sense.

Comment: err, thanks to this convo -> [Google thinks I'm interested in buying jewelery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIdnc.png)

Comment: @BhargavRao guess we'll have to start calling you "Bling Bling Rao" then :p (That's a "gem" of a name - it has a right "ring" to it... it's "golden" in fact... etc... etc... I'll stop now! :p)

Comment: How can I filter Close Vote queue by both type and tag? I can filter by type (click on "Duplicates"...) but don't know how to filter for a tag.

Comment: @jpp, you can type the tag name when you click the filter, there's a text box below the place where you clock on "duplicates"

Answer (score 17):

If you already have steward gold badge in the close review queue, you do not care much about review queue stats and you are disappointed with the close review queue because in many cases SE just age away your review time (too many questions, too few reviewers), its structure is inefficient and it is lacking the filters you would like.

We (community members) have developed a bot, [SOCVFinder](https://stackapps.com/questions/6910/socvfinder-providing-enjoyable-reviewing-live-duplicate-notifications-and-cher) that allows you to help out the peeps in the review queue avoiding that also their time in the queue is aged away.

With the bot, you can filter out questions on tag, number of close votes already present on question (review question with already 4cv that are aging away), score, no roomba (hence not reviewing questions that will be deleted anyway), no answers etc and you can open (load) all the questions contemporary in multiple tabs.

The bot, [Queen](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/6294609/queen) is present in different chat rooms (since it also feeds possible duplicates to gold badge hammers) but its home is [SOBotics chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics). Feel free to drop in and run your own September batch.

If you are an RO in a chat room and like to have a duplicate feed or simply the possibility to run batches in the room, just let us know and we can make the bee enter.

<sup>Affiliation: I'm one of the developers of the bot and an RO of the SOBotics chat room.</sup>

Answer (score 9):

While we are sharing closing-productivity tips, here is mine: get the newest 100-200 questions with their close/up/down/vote counts, then filter and sort by some measure of "closability" to get a list of likely targets. A simple script does all this for me, and it is available as a web app: [High-speed low-drag review](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw0e1JgXXH6F1f1R_9ZKNQ5wPNcNOPfK7rNW68ohyWIvf0pDiI/exec).